# equation builder using loops

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a program that iterates through all possible simple equations to find a value of 24. I managed to get the loop done but there is something I'm not catching.

The idea is theres a 3 level loop (i guess theta(n^3)?, im bad with time complexity), this is used to build an equation with 4 numbers (randomly generated early in the program) that are added to my list.

```
numList = [x2, x3, x4]
```

Here is the code I have:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        for k in range(4):
            for l in range(len(numList)):
                n += 1
                print(i, j, k, " i, j, k")
                print(x2, x3, x4, "x2, x3, x4")
                print(x, "x supposed to be reset")
                print(l, "val of l")
                print(n, "val of n")
                if i == 0 or j == 0 or k == 0:
                    x += "+"
                    x += str(numList[n])
                    print(x, "add")
                if i == 1 or j == 1 or k == 1:
                    x += "-"
                    x += str(numList[n])
                    print(x, "sub")
                if i == 2 or j == 2 or k == 2:
                    x += "*"
                    x += str(numList[n])
                    print(x, "mult")
                if i == 3 or j == 3 or k == 3:
                    x += "/"
                    x += str(numList[n])
                    print(x, "div")

                if n == 2:        
                    print()
                    print("----")
                    print(x, "final")
                    print(eval(x), "evald")
                    if eval(x) is not 24:
                        x = x1
                        print(x, "x reset")
                    else:
                        print(eval(x), "= 24")
                    n = -1
                    print("----")
```

The error comes in when, for some reason, the string I'm building and evaluating (x) does not reset, and instead adds to that same string generated in the last loop iteration (it's supposed to be the default value). The default value of x is randomly generated:

```
x = str(randrange(1, 9))
```

It's weird to me, I'm not sure what is going wrong, the loop is acting like a switch conditional statement without breaks. Here is my console output: [Pasted to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DUuh0Mrr)

**Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?** or what is going on in my code that I am not seeing 
Why is x not being reset as if it were a new string being built (this is what I want)?

Edit: here is the entire source: [equation.py](http://pastebin.com/sPBHt4ET)

Comment: Why not put x = "" where you want it to be reset? Btw, you should post enough code such that someone else can run your code and see the same bug as you.

Comment: @Patashu I want the original value of x to be the same at the start of the equation. I generated the value of x at the beginning of the program before this loop because I want it unaffected. 
I want it to always be the first number in the equation, as well as all the following numbers.

Comment: Well, you don't reset x if eval(x) is 24. Is that the problem?

Comment: No. The problem if x is eval() to 24. I'm eventually going to break out of the function (I didn't add that code yet). For now the program should just loop entirely through all possible equation arrangements. The issue is, when I have my final equation (x + x2 + x3 + x4) and that is not 24, I want x to become the default value so  can build an entirely new equation with it.

Comment: @Patashu say the loop generates the equation (2 + 5 + 3 + 8, with x starting at "2"), that's not 24. So when the loops starts over I want to have x be "2" again, so the loop handles the equation building from scratch. The loop basically concatenates values to my equation string, and the operations in between those number in the equation is determined by the loop. Based on my code the next equation x should be is (2 + 5 + 3 - 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't 'x isn't being reset'. The problem was that your code was not designed to use exactly three operators on each pass through. For example, if i was 0, j was 1 and k was 2 it would use + due to i being 0, - due to j being 1 and * due to k being 2, for every single number in the equation, so you'd see things like `1+5-5*5+6-6*6+4-4*4` with all of the operators repeated three times.

You want logic more like this, where you explicitly use three operators and iterate over all combinations of the three operators:

```
from random import randrange

def brute_force():
    x1 = randrange(1, 9)
    x2 = randrange(1, 9)
    x3 = randrange(1, 9)
    x4 = randrange(1, 9)
    numList = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
    operatorList = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
    equation = ""

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            for k in range(4):
                equation = str(numList[0]) + operatorList[i] + str(numList[1]) + operatorList[j] + str(numList[2]) + operatorList[k] + str(numList[3])
                print("equation: " + equation)
                print("evaluation: " + str(eval(equation)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    brute_force()
```

output looks like

```
>>> brute_force()
equation: 4+6+4+6
evaluation: 20
equation: 4+6+4-6
evaluation: 8
equation: 4+6+4/6
evaluation: 10
equation: 4+6+4*6
evaluation: 34
equation: 4+6-4+6
evaluation: 12
equation: 4+6-4-6
evaluation: 0
equation: 4+6-4/6
evaluation: 10
...
```

Comment: Wow... That seemed pretty obvious. I'm new to Python, it just makes things so, simple...
Or I'm just too slow for now, either way thank you!!

Comment: @mastrgamr When in doubt, ask yourself if you're structuring your program the right way. Or if it's doing what your mental model says it should (it often isn't). Or if you can write it simpler (The simpler you write code, and the more self-evident variable names and structures are, the easier it is to debug and appraise)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do an equation builder that doesn't rely on `eval`, and will also let you easily use any binary (2 arguments) function, and any order of operations:

```
class Operation():
    def __init__(self, func, precedence):
        self.func = func
        self.precedence = precedence
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.func(*args)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.func.__name__

class Equation():
    def __init__(self, numbers, operations):
        self.nums = list(numbers)
        self.ops = list(operations)
    def eval(self):
        while self.ops:
            min_op_precedence = min([x.precedence for x in self.ops])
            #get all pairs of numbers in the list [1,2,3] -> [(1,2), (2,3)]
            for index, pair in enumerate(zip(self.nums, self.nums[1:])):
                if self.ops[index].precedence == min_op_precedence:
                    #evaluate pair of numbers if the precedence for their op is highest
                    #ie "1 * 2 - 3" -> "2 - 3"
                    val = self.ops[index](*pair) 
                    self.nums.pop(index) 
                    self.nums[index] = val 
                    self.ops.pop(index)
                    break
        return self.nums.pop()
```

And here's how you would use it to find what permutation of operations gives a certain result, if such a permutation exists (using brute force):

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, floordiv
from itertools import permutations

numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
#operations with order of operations:
ops = [ Operation(*x) for x in [(mul, 1), (floordiv, 2), (sub, 3), (add, 4)] ] 

def findequation( numbers, ops, answer ):
    for p in permutations(ops, (len(numbers)-1)):
        if Equation( numbers, list(p) ).eval() == answer:
            return p
    return None

print findequation(numbers, ops, 0)
#>>> (sub, mul, floordiv)
#this means "1 - 2 * 3 / 4" = 0
```